# How to log output of just a specified framework class in Log4J

Tags: java, spring, log4j

I need to log the output of a specific Spring class (org.springframework.core.log.LogFormatUtils) to a given appender (Graylog in the end, but I used a FileAppender for testing purposes - doesn't matter here).
I'm aware that generally, this could be done quite simple by using

```
<Loggers>
        <Logger name="org.springframework.core.log.LogFormatUtils" level="DEBUG">
            <AppenderRef ref="FileAppender"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="debug" includeLocation="true">
            <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
        </Root>
</Loggers>
```

However, this does not work - it outputs nothing. If I change the logger's name / package reference to "org.springframework" it works as expcted, but I'm not interested in the bunch of inforamtion coming along that way. Additionally, if I denote something like com.myapp.mypackage, it also works.
So, are there some caveats or steps to perform before I can log Spring framework output in general?

Comment: The class `LogFormatUtils` doesn't log anything itself, so there will never be a logger with the name `LogFormatUtils` and thus nothing will be logged. So basically it works as it should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```java
public static void traceDebug(Log logger, Function<Boolean, String> messageFactory) {
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        boolean traceEnabled = logger.isTraceEnabled();
        String logMessage = messageFactory.apply(traceEnabled);
        if (traceEnabled) {
            logger.trace(logMessage);
        }
        else {
            logger.debug(logMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

The method is the only method in the `LogFormatUtils` class that uses the Log object, but the Log object it uses is passed from other classes, that is to say, logger name of the Log object is not `org.springframework.core.log.LogFormatUtils`, you can change logger's name to `org.springframework` and add `%logger` to PatternLayout to find the real logger's name you need.

Comment: This was very helpful - the actual logger's name is org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet (which logs other things, too, so I have to apply more filtering in order to get just the LogFormatUtils output).